# Post requests from Angular app to firebase database

Tags: angular, firebase, http, firebase-realtime-database

I have created a photo gallery app using Angular and I want to add a new user to a users array which is stored in a firebase database when a new user registers on the app. I have only just started making http requests and using firebase and I am struggling to get my head around how it works (I have read the firebase docs).

This is the post request method I have created:

```
 addUser(email: string, name: string) {
        return this.http.post('https://photo-gallery-dd8b6.firebaseio.com/users.json', {
            email: email,
            name: name
        }).subscribe(response => {
            console.log(response);
        })
    }
```

This is where the method is called:

```
const name = this.logInForm.value.name;
const email = this.logInForm.value.email;

this.logInService.addUser(email, name);
```

The values are retrieved from an Angular form.

The issue I am having is when the user it added to the firebase database it stores them as nested objects with a strange key which is automatically generated by firebase:

[image]

I guess what I am trying to achieve is that there would be an array of user objects with the object names being the users email address and the property of that object being the users name.

Would the best way to go about this be by saving the array of users locally and then using a put request to save the users array to the database when the app initializes and when a new user is added? Hope this all makes sense to someone!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
addUser(email: string, name: string) {
  const data = {
      [email]: {email,name}
    };

  return this.http.put('https://photo-gallery-dd8b6.firebaseio.com/users.json',
      data).subscribe(response => {console.log(response);})
}
```

Notice that:

1. I'm specifying the email as the id
2. Because I'm specifying the id, I'm using `PUT`, not `POST` `HTTP` method.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have changed the addUser method to your suggestion but I receive a 400 error from the http request and nothing is saved to the firebase realtime database?

Comment: Maybe that's because you already have other users created by firebase with its id generation scheme. If it's possible, try it in another collection (like `user2`). According to [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data#section-put), what we are doing it right.